# Austrian School Regret Theory

Tags: self-study

I am having a time thinking about how Ruthbard and Mises speak about trade agreements and the concept that every economic transaction is just because it is voluntary and subjectively benefits both parties, at least ex ante of the agreement.

But I would like to know the moral and economic ground that the Austrians and sympathetic of the Austrian School give to the ex post regret.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Giskard I Want to get recommended leture/text/papers to get a general perspective without reading too much

Comment: But what do you mean by "*moral and economic ground* [of] *ex post regret*"? If we make a bet (or a contract where the state of the world is somewhat random), and I lose (turns out the state of the world is such that the contract is ex post not beneficial), I will be sad, because I lost money. Not sure what aspect of this you want to explore.

Comment: @Giskard I want to know how the Austrian School claims that even with ex post regret the market is the most efficient system, and what moral system tend to bid the members of the Austrian School to say it is fair.

Comment: Okay; for clarity's sake can you please give a reference where "*the Austrian School claims that even with ex post regret the market is the most efficient system*"?